Only the didFetchResult deligate method is not invoked in Sensorkit
import Foundation
import SensorKit
import UIKit

final class SensorKitManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SRSensorReaderDelegate {
    
    static let shared = SensorKitManager()
    
    private let ambientReader = SRSensorReader(sensor: .ambientLightSensor)
    
    private var availableDevices: [SRDevice] = []
    
    @Published var ambientLightData: [AmbientLightDataPoint] = []
    
    var isFetching = false
    var isRecordingAmbientLight = false
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        setupReaders()
        checkAndRequestAuthorization()
    }
    
    private func setupReaders() {
        ambientReader.delegate = self
    }
    
    // MARK: - 권한 설정
    
    func requestAuthorization() {
        SRSensorReader.requestAuthorization(sensors: [.ambientLightSensor]) { [weak self] error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let self = self else {
                    print("권한 요청 중단")
                    return
                }
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("권한 요청 실패: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    if (error as NSError).code == SRError.promptDeclined.rawValue {
                        print("사용자 권한 거부")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("권한 요청 성공")
                    self.startRecordingAmbientLightData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkAndRequestAuthorization() {
        let status = ambientReader.authorizationStatus
        
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("조도 센서 접근 허용됨")
            startRecordingAmbientLightData()
            
        case .notDetermined:
            print("조도 센서 접근 미결정, 권한 요청 시작")
            requestAuthorization()
        case .denied:
            print("조도 센서에 대한 접근 거부 또는 제한됨")
            // 필요한 경우 사용자에게 설정에서 권한을 변경하도록 안내하는 로직
        @unknown default:
            print("알 수 없는 권한 상태입니다.")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - 조도 값 로직
    
    func startRecordingAmbientLightData() {
        guard !isRecordingAmbientLight else {
            print("이미 조도 데이터 기록 중입니다.")
            return
        }
        
        print("조도 데이터 기록 시작")
        isRecordingAmbientLight = true
        ambientReader.startRecording()
        fetchAmbientDeviceData()
        fetchAmbientLightData()
        triggerDummyFetchResult()
    }
    
    private func fetchAmbientDeviceData() {
        print("디바이스 정보 페치 시작")
        let fetchRequest = SRFetchRequest()
        
        // 48시간 전부터 24시간 전까지의 데이터 요청 (대기 기간을 벗어난 데이터)
        let fromDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-72 * 60 * 60)
        let toDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60)
        
        fetchRequest.from = SRAbsoluteTime(fromDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        fetchRequest.to = SRAbsoluteTime(toDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        
        if availableDevices.isEmpty {
            print("디바이스 없음")
            ambientReader.fetchDevices()
        } else {
            for device in availableDevices {
                print("데이터 페치 시작 (디바이스: \(device))")
                fetchRequest.device = device
                ambientReader.fetch(fetchRequest)
                print("페치 요청 보냄 (디바이스: \(device))")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAmbientLightData() {
        guard !isFetching else {
            print("이미 페치 중입니다.")
            return
        }
        
        isFetching = true
        
        let fetchRequest = SRFetchRequest()
        let now = Date()
        let fromDate = now.addingTimeInterval(-72 * 24 * 60 * 60)
        let toDate = now.addingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60) // 24시간 전
        fetchRequest.from = SRAbsoluteTime(fromDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        fetchRequest.to = SRAbsoluteTime(toDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        fetchRequest.device = SRDevice.current
        
        ambientReader.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    
    private func displayAmbientLightData(sample: SRAmbientLightSample) {
        print("조도: \(sample.lux.value) lux")
        
        // ambientLightData 배열의 전체 내용을 추가로 출력
        print("현재 ambientLightData 내용:")
        for data in ambientLightData {
            print("Timestamp: \(data.timestamp), Lux: \(data.lux)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Dummy Test
    
    func triggerDummyFetchResult() {
        print("더미 데이터로 didFetchResult 호출 테스트")
        
        // 실제로 데이터가 패치될 수 있는지 테스트할 수 있는 요청을 만들고 호출
        fetchAmbientLightData()  // 실 데이터를 통해 패치 시도
    }


    
    // MARK: - SRSensorReaderDelegate 메서드
    
    func sensorReader(_ reader: SRSensorReader, didFetch devices: [SRDevice]) {
        print("장치 페치 : \(devices.count)개")
        
        availableDevices = devices
        
        for device in devices {
            print("페치된 장치: \(device)")
        }
        
        if !devices.isEmpty {
            fetchAmbientDeviceData()
        }
    }
    
    func sensorReader(_ reader: SRSensorReader, didCompleteFetch fetchRequest: SRFetchRequest) {
        print("데이터 페치 완료")
        isFetching = false
        
        // 현재 시간 기준으로 24시간 전과 72시간 전 시간 계산
        let now = Date()
        let twentyFourHoursAgo = now.addingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60)
        let seventyTwoHoursAgo = now.addingTimeInterval(-72 * 60 * 60)
        
        // 페치된 데이터 중 24시간에서 72시간 사이의 데이터만 필터링
        let filteredData = ambientLightData.filter { dataPoint in
            dataPoint.timestamp >= seventyTwoHoursAgo && dataPoint.timestamp <= twentyFourHoursAgo
        }
        
        if filteredData.isEmpty {
            print("24시간에서 72시간 사이의 조도 데이터가 없습니다.")
            // 필요한 경우 기본 데이터 추가
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let defaultTimestamp = twentyFourHoursAgo
                let dataPoint = AmbientLightDataPoint(timestamp: defaultTimestamp, lux: 10.0)
                self.ambientLightData.append(dataPoint)
                print("ambientLightData에 추가된 기본 조도 값: 0.0 lux, Timestamp: \(defaultTimestamp)")
            }
        } else {
            // 필터링된 데이터로 ambientLightData 업데이트
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.ambientLightData = filteredData
                print("24시간에서 72시간 사이의 조도 데이터 \(filteredData.count)개를 추가했습니다.")
                // 데이터 로깅
                for dataPoint in filteredData {
                    print("추가된 조도 값: \(dataPoint.lux) lux, Timestamp: \(dataPoint.timestamp)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sensorReader(_ reader: SRSensorReader, fetching fetchRequest: SRFetchRequest, didFetchResult result: SRFetchResult<AnyObject>) -> Bool {
        print("sensorReader(_:fetching:didFetchResult:) 메서드 호출됨")
        
        if let ambientSample = result.sample as? SRAmbientLightSample {
            print("Lux value: \(ambientSample.lux.value)")
            
            // 추가 로직: 중복된 데이터가 있는지 확인하고 없을 때만 추가
            let timestamp = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: result.timestamp.rawValue)
            if !ambientLightData.contains(where: { $0.timestamp == timestamp }) {
                let dataPoint = AmbientLightDataPoint(timestamp: timestamp, lux: Float(ambientSample.lux.value))
                ambientLightData.append(dataPoint)
                print("ambientLightData에 추가된 조도 값: \(ambientSample.lux.value) lux, Timestamp: \(timestamp)")
            } else {
                print("중복된 데이터이므로 추가하지 않음: Timestamp: \(timestamp)")
            }
            
            // 데이터 출력
            self.displayAmbientLightData(sample: ambientSample)
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    
    func sensorReader(_ reader: SRSensorReader, fetching fetchRequest: SRFetchRequest, failedWithError error: Error) {
        print("페치 요청 실패: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func sensorReaderWillStartRecording(_ reader: SRSensorReader) {
        print("레코딩 시작됨")
    }
    
    func sensorReaderDidStopRecording(_ reader: SRSensorReader) {
        print("조도 데이터 기록 중단됨")
        isRecordingAmbientLight = false
    }
    
    func sensorReader(_ reader: SRSensorReader, startRecordingFailedWithError error: Error) {
        print("레코딩 시작 실패: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }



It's a question about implementing SensorKit Deligate. Currently, you can add entry with all the privileges to get device information.
But why isn't only the value of didFetchResult that gets the illuminance value called out of the deligate methods.. Other deligate methods are called well (ex device call related method, didCompleteFetch, etc.) Please help
The permissions to the SensorKit are normally received and data can be called, including other Deligate methods and permission settings. Currently, the illumination values that can be shared within the actual device are checked, but the method calling the Deligate illumination value in the code is not called.

Show us the code where you set yourself as the delegate of SensorKit. And are you saying that other delegate methods are being called, but not the sensorReader(_:fetching:didFetchResult:) method. If so can you show another delegate method that *is being called?

Code in comments is unreadable. Please edit your question to include that extra code.

And let us know which delegate methods are being called and which are not.

Currently, I have forwarded you the full code at the bottom, please check and thank you so much for trying to help.

Thank you for letting me know, I have corrected your question!
The issue at the moment is that the didFetchResult is not the only Deligate method being called. What I've found is that I can import past 24 hours of data, and it's present on the device, but it doesn't seem to be getting it right.
